# Problema al actualizar cambios en firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

Muy buenas, estaba realizando una página con `angular` y surgió el siguiente problema, cuando hice el deploy en `firebase` quise loguearme a la página y no funcionaba, en la consola veía que estaba intentando hacer la petición a la `url` que utilizaba de manera local... inmediatamente hice los cambios para que haga la petición a la `url` donde estaba hosteada la api...
después intenté hacer el deploy siguiendo las siguientes lineas:

```
ng build
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Bien, cuando intento loguearme nuevamente me sigue apareciendo en la consola que sigue intentando hacer la petición a la `url` local (*ya habiendo modificado las url's y hecho el deploy nuevamente*)
¿algo que pueda hacer para que se vean los cambios?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

- Me pongo en la carpeta que contiene **src** y ejecuto:

  ```
  npm run build
  ```

  Tengo entendido es el equivalente a `ng build` en angular (yo uso react).
- Luego arrastro la carpeta dist que se crea hacia afuera, donde tengo **`firebase.json`**.
- Luego ejecuto `firebase deploy` para poder acceder desde el link que termina en `**web.app`** y finalmente `firebase deploy --only` hosting para poder ver los cambios en **`firebase.app`**.